# Magento 2: Custom Category Attribute - Image Upload Ajax 404

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I've downloaded the following module (just to save time: https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-category-image) which should add an image attribute to the category page in the admin panel which it does; however, I keep getting the following error when I try to upload an image:

```
POST https://www.example.com/admin/categoryimage/category_mobile/upload/key/b1da8d66c447c86971b2a9f0f8092b245cb3d4e947cc1f5ba03fc2d79574138f/?isAjax=true 404
```

I've double-checked the routes.xml file and I can't see anything out of the ordinary. I've also tried to move the module into another folder (app/code/testimagecategory/CategoryImage/) and changed all of the references from /SR to /testimagecategory however it didn't work.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create folder app/code/SR/CategoryImage/
2. Then copy all files and folder according the github link and run magento command like below

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Then check it.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Testimagecategory\CategoryImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnail\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="testimagecategory\CategoryImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Mobile\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save">
        <plugin name="testimagecategory_image_preprocessing" type="testimagecategory\CategoryImage\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\SavePlugin" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="Testimagecategory_category_data_provider" type="Testimagecategory\CategoryImage\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: I've ran through the installation and ran those commands. The attribute is visible in the backend however when I try to upload an image, I get the Ajax 404 error that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: please clear cache through command line and logout in admin then check it

Comment: I've cleared the cache through CLI and redeployed the codebase, it's still not playing ball unfortunately.

Comment: can you show me your di.xml file? you are trying to upload image using mobile am I right?

Comment: check my answer sir because I have try this extension in my local and it works

Comment: I've just changed my config, cleared the relevant DB tables and reinstalled the module and it's working now.

That's Magento 2 for you!

Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204721/discussion-between-jinesh-and-jazz-singh).